# Load array of images at random

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, imagelist

I developed a gallery of small images. I intend to have two distinct arrays, an array names and an images array.

When loading the array names, several "squares" are created that contain the name and src for the image.

Is there a way to place random images in "squares" and keep the array of names in it?

[**DEMO - STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejwlnp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="mdc-image-list my-image-list">
    <li class="mdc-image-list__item" *ngFor="let cat of names">
        <div class="mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container">
            <img [src]=""
              class="mdc-image-list__image imagelistCatalog">
          </div>
            <div class="mdc-image-list--with-text-protection">
                <div class="mdc-image-list__supporting supportingCatalog">
                    <span class="mdc-image-list__label textLabelCatalog">{{cat.name}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**TS**

```
names=[
  {
   name:"name1"
},
  {
     name:"name1"
},
  {
     name:"name1"
},
  {
     name:"name1"
}]

images=[
  {
   img:"https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/3x2/6.jpg"
},
  {
     img:"https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/3x2/5.jpg"
},
  {
     img:"https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/3x2/3.jpg"
},
  {
     img:"https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/2x3/2.jpg"
}]
```

[image: iMAGES]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Component.ts file
 newArr = []
 ngOnInit(): void {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < this.names.length; i++){
      this.newArr[i] = {};
      this.newArr[i]['name'] = this.names[i].name;
      this.newArr[i]['img'] = this.imgRand();
    }
 }
 
 imgRand(){
    let img = this.images[Math.floor(Math.random() *    this.images.length)];
    return img.img;
 }
```

```html
 <li class="mdc-image-list__item" *ngFor="let cat of newArr">
  <div class="mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container">
    <img [src]="cat.img" class="mdc-image-list__image imagelistCatalog">
  </div>
  <div class="mdc-image-list--with-text-protection">
    <div class="mdc-image-list__supporting supportingCatalog">
      <span class="mdc-image-list__label textLabelCatalog">{{cat.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Create a new function in your component.ts file that returns a random image name from your array of images.

In your component.html file, at the img src call that new function ... img [src]="yourFunctionName()". This will work, but doing so would probably generate a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in your console.

What I would recommend is that you create a new array, and in the ngOnInit lifecycle method,loop through the names array, create a new object with the keys 'name' and 'image' (using your new random function),push it to your new array and use that in your component.html file at *ngFor instead.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest create an array "order" and iterate over order, some like

```
order:number[]

ngOnInit()
{
  this.order=this.images.map((n,index)=>index); //create an array [0,1,2,3..]
  this.order.sort((a,b)=>Math.random()>.5);  //shuffle the array
}
```

Then use

```
<li class="mdc-image-list__item" *ngFor="let index of order">
   {{images[index]}}{{names[index]}}
</li>
```

NOTE: you can improve the app if you use an array of object, not two arrays. e.g. if you has

```
images=[{img:"...",name:".."},{img:"...",name:".."},{img:"...",name:".."}..]
```

And use

```
<li class="mdc-image-list__item" *ngFor="let index of order">
   {{images[index].img}}{{images[index].name}}
</li>
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fe49yy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I tried to implement your solution but it didn't work, the images and the name don't appear correctly

Comment: @SteveMc, I updated my answer adding a stackblitz, I hope this help you (I use lorem ipsum to get the images), if you refresh the page you will see the images in other order

Comment: Thanks again for the dedication. There is a way to achieve this but using the two objects and not just one. Basically I will have a service running, this service sends me the name and the images I will upload them in a physical folder (using /assets/img.jpg), hence using two objects.

Comment: of course, if you has two arrays "names" and "images" use the same index: names[index].name and images[index].img. I don't know how you receive the data from the service, but other option is create the array object using the two values

Comment: Because this way I only use one object